# htaccess rewrite all with document_general_info in the url

Tags: .htaccess

I need to be able to rewrite all urls that have document_general_info in the url.
Example urls would be like:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?main_page=document_general_info&cPath=2371_2377_2407_2606&products_id=27990


www.mysite.com/index.php?main_page=document_general_info&cPath=2371_2373&products_id=23055
```

I need to redirect them to index.php as they are historical links for content that no longer exists and will give me over 3000 404 errors

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?.*document_general_info [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php? [L,R]
```

Change R to R=301 (Permanent redirect) when you are sure the rule is working ok.

Comment: Why use `THE_REQUEST` rather than `QUERY_STRING`?

Comment: QUERY_STRING isnt safe it can cause an infinite loop error if OP is using another rewrite rule to handle the same request.

Comment: That works perfectly.
One question, will that tell spiders that the page it visited no longer exists, allowing the url's to be dropped from indexes after a while?